# How to call a Python class instance from a list?

Tags: python

I would like to be able to select the class' property by it's name. This is my code:

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = "1"
        self.two = "2"

x = example()
list = ["one", "two"]
# I want to get x.one here by referring to it by list[0]
```

How can I do this?

Worked example:

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = "one"
        self.two = "two"

    def test(self):
        list = ["one", "two"]
        print(getattr(self, list[1]))

x = example()

x.test()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your terminology doesn't match the code you posted, and that code is unclear.

Comment: I have fixed the question for you John, hopefully that's what you're trying to ask. The answers are already available below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access object properties by their name, try this:

```
list = ['one', 'two']
print getattr(x, list[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic attribute access in Python is provided with the built-in function [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
>>> getattr(x, list_[1])
'2'
>>> [getattr(x, name) for name in list_]
['1', '2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `getattr` function:

```
getattr(x, list[1])
```